# Why didn't the Terra Nova mission arrive after the era of dinosaurs?

Tags: tv, terra-nova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did the people of 2149 evacuate to 85,000,000 B.C. particularly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6122/why-did-the-people-of-2149-evacuate-to-85-000-000-b-c-particularly)

If they arrived in the post dinosaur past it would be safer since fossil fuel won't hunt you down and eat you. Why did they send the Terra Nova people back 85 million years instead of, oh say, 50 million years?

Comment: I must have glossed over that one. My bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I can't quote any kind of source, I seem to recall that the time fissure was discovered accidentally and they didn't have any measure of control over when it led to.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. They should have used a Delorean!