# How was the new batch of people transported to Terra Nova after destination time increment?

Tags: tv, time-travel, terra-nova

From the question: [Why did the people of 2149 evacuate to 85,000,000 B.C. particularly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6122/why-did-the-people-of-2149-evacuate-to-85-000-000-b-c-particularly), they discovered a fracture in time and space, which they were able to use to transport anything to 85 million years B.C. They didn't have their choice of destination time as

> They were unable to CREATE a fracture in time and space on their own.

Then, how did they send people to several years later? For example, our heroes arrived in Terra Nova 7 years after Captain Taylor. How is this possible when the destination time wasn't under their control?

Comment: Presumably, the portal ends are subject to the progression of time.  Therefore, if you send one thing in and then a second thing five minutes after, the second thing will arrive on the other end five minutes after the first.

Comment: Aren't the two timelines strictly increasing, but not necessarily at the same rate? I think I remember them mentioning that Commander Taylor has to spend some extended amount of days/months alone in the jungle, even though the second person to go through the portal stepped in a few moments after him. Or am I just making that up?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo I remember the same thing.  It was somewhere around 4 months he spent on his own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fissure was a direct line to that area in the past, and as the time in 2149 moved forward, the time in Terra Nova moved forward.  So the fissure always went through a specific number of years, months, days, hours, and minutes.

When time in the 2140s moved forward 1 minute, so did time in Terra Nova, and the fissure kept the two in sync.  Think of the fissure as a set length of pipe, and as one end moved, the other moved with it.

Comment: This seems most likely given the pilgrimages we see, but how do you explain the extended amount of time Taylor spent alone?

Comment: That was explained in one of the later episodes.  I don't remember exactly, but either it wasn't anchored at that point, or there wasn't even power flow in the 2140s, so things didn't "line up" like they do later.